# Defining colour constants in a Java file, not xml

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-color

Are there any pitfalls to defining colours as `int` constants, and accessing them statically, over pulling them from `xml` every time they are required?

For example, say I define a class called `AppColors`:

```
public final class AppColors {

    private AppColors() { throw new AssertionError(); }

    public static final int COLOR_RED_500 = 0xFFF44336;

}
```

And access the colour with `AppColors.COLOR_RED_500`, whereas the usual route is `getResources().getColor(R.color.red_500)`.

Aside from the fact that the colour would probably need to be defined twice, once in `xml` for layout/themes and again in code, defining colours in this way would have the advantage of not requiring repeated `getResources()` calls and the need to pass `Context` arguments to methods and constructors of classes that do not inherit from the `Context` class.

Comment: Actually making a call to `getResources()` requires `context` of the particular class, so maybe accessing color by `getresources().getColor()` is little heavy than accessing it as `YourColorClass.colorName` but the time or resources accessing difference would be negligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to check the case that suits your needs but here are some arguments against.

1. You listed the major argument in your question, about defining it
   twice.
2. You can override the colour in different values files
   if you so desired, for example a different colour for a different
   language, screen orientation etc.
3. You can use the colour in the layout xmls.

To read more on the subject, try reading this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html.

Comment: I hadn't considered the advantages that come from creating different `color` `xml` files for different configurations (orientation etc). I think your post covers the main pros/cons.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is not a defined convention for this.

---

Which matters most in this cases is

- clarity
- performance
- scalability

If, in your case, this remove declaration duplicates and makes your code clearer, not affecting performance, **yes, you can and MUST use it**.

**But note:** this is not a general rule, you must analize each case individually and decide wisely, for other cases, use `AppColors` class may create duplicities or performance problems (if many requests) instead of using database table.

Comment: Did you say performance issues could arise from making many requests to constants? Would you be able to expand on that please?

Comment: Nope, I mean many requests on dabase, if your app makes several requests using database those requests may decrease performance... actually, in this case, static classes will be instantiated once and access to constants will be faster.

Comment: Usuallly if I have to access many times to a DB table, I populate Java objects in order to increase performance and data transfer due remote connections.

Answer (score 1):

No. Its totally up to you where you define the colors. The advantage of keeping them in xml is you can use those colors in your xml layouts/themes as well.

Eg:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_red_500" />
```

If you're fed up passing `Context` to extract colors, I would suggest you to have a static singleton instance for your `Application` class

Eg:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication instance;

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

Then use it like `MyApplication.getInstance().getResources().getColor(R.color.red_500);`

Comment: Nice suggestion, and yes, part of the issue is in fact in the amount of code required to pass `Context`, then store each colour in a variable, etc. Accessing an instance in this way would speed up the process.